# How to use brunch with Vue

Tags: django, vue.js, brunch

I'm trying to use brunch with Vue and Django, but I get a blank page and when I try to put breakpoints in my js, I see that it fails on:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'
```

with 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier'

My html is:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        ...
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'public/css/app.css' %}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
          <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'public/js/vendors.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'public/js/app.js' %}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My js is:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter);
...
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    ...
}).$mount('#app');
```

My brunch config is:

```
module.exports = {
    files: {
        javascripts: {
            joinTo: { 
                "js/vendors.js": /^node_modules/,
                'js/app.js': /^js/
            }
        },
        stylesheets: {joinTo: { 'css/app.css': 'scss/main.scss'}},
        templates: {
            joinTo: 'js/app.js'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        watched: ['js', 'scss']
    },
    plugins: {
        babel: {
            presets: ['es2015']
        }
    }
};
```

For some reason in browser sources I see my js compiled, the whole node_modules dir compiled and original js folder not compiled.
Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at **[this](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/08/20/vue-js-brunch/)** blog post that walks through setting up vuejs with brunch, it's fairly new and has a github repo which you can test against.

Also, seems like ur missing `require('app')` after your app.js script.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you miss babel (or any other javascript "compiler") to transpile your next generation javascript syntax into something your browser understands today. Especially the import syntax has not yet arrived in current browsers.

For brunch there is for example [tomquirk/brunch-vue-barebones](https://github.com/tomquirk/brunch-vue-barebones) skeleton, which handles this for you.

Comment: Nope. It doesn't help. I have exactly the same problem

Comment: Can you please provide the full trace? Does your brunch config includes somthing like `plugins: { babel: { presets: ['es2015'] } }`?

Comment: Yes. I updated the question. I see in the browser that app.js is fine and without imports. But I see an empty page and when I try to put breakpoints in app.js, I jump to the described error in my original js file